# Finding the Longest Path in a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, path, binary-tree, nodes, depth-first-search

I want to find the longest path in a Binary Tree. I plan to add them to a list, that way I can tell my enemy character to take the long path on easy mode.

```
private static <T> ArrayList<T> depthFirstSearch(BinaryNode<T> node)
{
    if(node != null)
    {
        Stack<BinaryNode<T>> stack = new Stack<BinaryNode<T>>();

        stack.push(node);

        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            BinaryNode<T> currentNode = stack.pop();



            if(currentNode.right != null)
                stack.push(currentNode.right);

            // We want to visit left child first, so push left node last.
            if(currentNode.left != null) 
                stack.push(currentNode.left);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written that code, but it is a mess. I am trying to use DFS to find the longest path to take. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I do have the height of the tree, I can get it using this.

```
public static <T> int height(BinaryNode<T> t)
{
    if (t == null)
        return -1;

    else 
        return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
}
```

My issue is: **when do I know that I have found the longest path using DFS so that I can add nodes to my list?**

Comment: sounds like a homework / assignment .

Comment: If you wrote the binary tree class, you can keep a record of its height and width, sometimes useful to determine what type of search to use.

Comment: You need to define "path".  Do you mean root-to-leaf path?  Or do you mean the longest path from some leaf to any other leaf?  There's a big difference.

Comment: Yes I will give it the root and from it I will try to find the longest path, which may not be the root. It could be left of root to right of root. For example, in a tree in preFix abc the root is a but the longest path is bac. The root I am passing is just the Tree, it holds no particular meaning besides just holding all the children below.

Comment: So any arbitrary path, as long as it is the longest path in the tree? In the context of your question (a game bot) it makes little sense if you do not specify at least the starting position as well?

Comment: Also, if it's a graph, your longest path might be REALLY long, up to visiting all the nodes, and it might not end up being what you actually want.

Comment: Yes as long as it is the longest path. I want to make the enemies spawn where the path starts, on that node.

Answer (score 8):

The longest path in a tree, is called "diameter". You can see the implementation of the algorithm here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/

Comment: @Vinay: Diameter of a tree is the longest path!

Comment: @MajidDarabi path in a tree - is a contiguous nodes sequence, that can be traversed only using pointers (to left and right leaves), diameter is not a path!

Comment: @VladislavYaroslavlev Could you add a reference to your definition of a path in a tree?? (a scientific paper or a book) because based on the general definition of a path in a graph, I could not conclude your definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29

Answer (score 2):

Check the answer given by Niki in the following link.. That is O(n) solution

[Diameter of Binary Tree - Better Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897088/diameter-of-binary-tree-better-design/19122726#19122726)

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this answer in case any one need it. Here is my solution in c++.
The function `Get_Max_Path()` returns a vector with the longest path itself so you got the path, it's length and it's sum if needed:

```cpp
vector<int> Max_Path(vector<int>rightpath, vector<int>leftpath)
{
    return (rightpath.size() > leftpath.size()) ? rightpath : leftpath;
}

vector<int> GetPath(node* N, vector<int> v)
{
    v.push_back(N->Data);
    return v;
}
vector<int> Get_Max_Path(node* root)
{
    if (!root) return 
        vector<int>(0);
    return Max_Path(GetPath( root, Get_Max_Path(root->Right)), 
                    GetPath( root, Get_Max_Path(root->Left)) );
}
```

And here is the tree structure

```cpp
class node
{
public:
    node* Right = NULL;
    node* Left = NULL;
    int Data;
};

class Tree
{
private:
    node* Root = NULL;

public:

    void Insert_Node(int Data)
    {
        node* DataNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        DataNode->Data = Data;
        DataNode->Left = DataNode->Right = NULL;

        if (Root == NULL) {
            Root = DataNode;
            return;
        }

        node* tmp_root = Root, * prev = NULL;
        while (tmp_root != NULL)
        {
            prev = tmp_root;
            tmp_root = (tmp_root->Data < Data) ?
                tmp_root->Right :
                tmp_root->Left;
        }
        (prev->Data < Data) ? (prev->Right = DataNode) : (prev->Left = DataNode);
    }

    vector<int> Max_Path(vector<int>rightpath, vector<int>leftpath)
    {
        return (rightpath.size() > leftpath.size()) ? rightpath : leftpath;
    }
    vector<int> Update_Path(node* N, vector<int> v)
    {
        v.push_back(N->Data);
        return v;
    }
    vector<int> Get_Max_length_Path(node* root)
    {
        if (!root) return
            vector<int>(0);
        return Max_Path(
            Update_Path(root, Get_Max_length_Path(root->Right)),
            Update_Path(root, Get_Max_length_Path(root->Left)));
    }

    vector<int> Get_Max_length_Path()
    {
        return Get_Max_length_Path(Root);
    }
};
```

This is the driver Code

```cpp
int main()
{
    Tree T;

    int nodes[] = { 11, 6, 8, 19, 4, 13, 5, 17, 43, 49, 16, 31, 32};
    int length = sizeof(nodes) / sizeof(nodes[0]);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        T.Insert_Node(nodes[i]);

    int sum = 0;

    vector<int> path = T.Get_Max_length_Path();
    cout << "The path length is : " << path.size() <<endl;
    cout << "The path from the leaf to the root is : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << path[i] << " ";
        sum += path[i] ;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "the path sum is :" << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test Case

BST sample
[image: BST sample]

Output

```
The path length is : 5 The path from the leaf to the root is : 16 17
13 19 11 the path sum is :76
```