# Time complexity for finding the diameter of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, time-complexity

I have seen various posts here that computes the diameter of a binary tree. One such solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897088/diameter-of-binary-tree-better-design#) (Look at the accepted solution, NOT the code highlighted in the problem).

I'm confused why the time complexity of the code would be O(n^2). I don't see how traversing the nodes of a tree twice (once for the height (via `getHeight()`) and once for the diameter (via `getDiameter()`) would be n^2 instead of n+n which is 2n. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the time complexity of `getHeight()` is `O(n)`.
For each node, the function `getHeight()` is called. So the complexity for a single node is `O(n)`. Hence the complexity for the entire algorithm (for all nodes) is `O(n*n)`.

Answer (score 2):

It should be O(N) to calculate the height of every subtree rooted at every node, you only have to traverse the tree one time using an in-order traversal.

```
int treeHeight(root)
{
   if(root == null) return -1;

   root->height = max(treeHeight(root->rChild),treeHeight(root->lChild)) + 1;
   return root->height;
}
```

This will visit each node 1 time, so has order O(N).

Combine this with the result from the linked source, and you will be able to determine which 2 nodes have the longest path between in at worst another traversal.

Indeed [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/diameter-of-a-binary-tree/) describes the way to do it in O(N)

The different between this solution (the optimized one) and the referenced one is that the referenced solution re-computes tree height every time  after shrinking the search size by only 1 node (the root node).  Thus from above the complexity will be O(N + (N - 1) + ... + 1).

The sum

```
1 + 2 + ... + N
```

is equal to

```
= N(N + 1)/2
```

And so the complexity of sum of all the operations from the repeated calls to getHeight will be O(N^2)

For completeness sake, conversely, the optimized solution getHeight() will have complexity O(1) after the pre computation because each node will store the value as a data member of the node.

Comment: I'm not looking for an optimized solution which works in O(n). I want to know why the solution I mentioned in my question has the time complexity of O(n^2)?

Answer (score 0):

All subtree heights may be precalculated (using O(n) time), so what total time complexity of finding the diameter would be O(n).

Comment: I'm not looking for an optimized solution which works in O(n). I want to know why the solution I mentioned in my question has the time complexity of O(n^2)?